When does the Feast of Unleavened Bread begin?
I am having trouble knowing when the Feast of Unleavened Bread actually starts and if the Passover is part of the Feast or a procedure of its own.
This is what I saw:
Evening of 14th Day until Evening of 21st Day (Exodus 12 + Deut 16)
But i also saw this:
Passover is 14th Day, Feast is 15th day and lasts for seven days (Lev 23 + Num 28 + Joshua 5)
The thing is, if the Feast began on the 15th wouldn't the Feast last until the 22nd and not the 21st?
Here are the days organized to help you maybe visualize (the number refers to the day of the month and the letter e stands for evening):
Day 1: 14e - 15e (Day of Passover)
Day 2: 15e - 16e (Beginning of Feast?)
Day 3: 16e - 17e
Day 4: 17e - 18e
Day 5: 18e - 19e
Day 6: 19e - 20e
Day 7: 20e - 21e
Day 8: 21e - 22e (would only exist if Feast Began on the 15th day?)
Is there something I am missing or inserting into the text? Thank you.

A day begins at sunset so the evening of the 14th is the end of the 14th day of the month. Your list of 14e - 15e is inaccurate. It is neither the 14th or the 15th but is closer to describing the 15th. Also, since the lambs were killed at the evening and were roasted before eating. The Passover meal would have been eaten on the 15th in Egypt.

Answer
The Feast of Unleavened Bread (UB) begins on 15th day, that is, immediately on the following day of the Passover which falls on 14th.
Theoretically, Passover is not part of the UB feast and it has its own procedure.
Explanation
In all the passages the OP has cited, viz., Exodus 12, Deut 16, Lev 23, Num 28, and Joshua 5, the descriptions are all the same for both Passover and the Feast of UB.
But it is important to understand beforehand that a Biblical day begins at evening, continues through night and day and ends at the next evening. This is very important to grasp as otherwise the calculations will all go wrong.

Nissan 14th – at the beginning evening, at the twilight, they are to kill the lamb “without any blemish” and eat it without any leaven. It is a working day.

Nissan 15th – the Feast of UB begins. No leaven should be found at homes. This is a sacred day and hence no work is allowed.

Nissan 16th – the 2nd day of UB. No leaven at home. Working day.

Nissan 17th – the 3rd day of UB. No leaven at home. Working day.

Nissan 18th – the 4th day of UB. No leaven at home. Working day.

Nissan 19th – the 5th day of UB. No leaven at home. Working day.

Nissan 20th – the 6th day of UB. No leaven at home. Working day.

Nissan 21st – the 7th day (last day) of UB. No leaven at home. This is a sacred day and hence no work is allowed.


Practical Application
Though the Passover and the Feast of UB are 2 different celebrations, the latter follows the former close on the heels and hence these began to be considered as one feast of 8 days on practical ground.
During the time of Jesus, we see this mentioned in the NT as the practice in prevalence.
For example, Mat 26:17 says that on the first day of the UB, they are to eat the Passover. Mark 14:12 also says the same thing. Same is the case with Luke 22:7. All of them describe the current Jewish practice of clubbing together the 1 day of Passover and the 7 days of UB calling them "as UB".
Luke 22:1 says that the UB is “being called Passover”. This is 1 + 7 days together.
But Mark 14:1 says the 1 + 7 days are called "Passover AND the Feast of UB".
So, the point is that practically 1 day Passover + 7 days UB are called together either as "UB" or as "Passover" or as "Passover and UB".
Symbolism
Passover symbolizes the perfect sacrifice of Jesus Christ who had “no sin” (2 Cor 5:21). Jesus was "the Lamb of God" (John 1:29) "without blemish (sin) and without spot" (1 Pet 1:19). Apostle Paul clearly identifies Jesus as our Passover Lamb in the New Testament:

“For also Christ our Passover was sacrificed for us” (1 Cor 5:7).

“Our” refers to the New Testament Christian believers. So, according to Paul, Passover is a New Testament feast to be celebrated.
The Feast of UB symbolizes the freedom from sin forever. 7 is a number of God that shows perfection. Egypt with its slavery is considered to be the present Age with the slavery of sin. King Pharaoh represents Satan who wants the children of Israel back as slaves. Satan wants people to be under sin again. But God is a great Deliverer.
Apostle Paul has this to say, referring to the Feat of UB:

“Then purge out the old leaven (sin) so that you may be a new
lump (a new creation), even as you are unleavened (saved from
sin, hence sinless). For also Christ our Passover was sacrificed for
us. So let us keep the feast (of UB), not with old leaven
(sin), nor with leaven of malice and of evil, but with
unleavened (sinless) bread of sincerity and truth” (1 Cor 5:7-8).

Removing leaven from our life refers to the Feast of UB. So Paul and the Apostles kept both the Passover and UB in the New Testament era.
It is pointless to keep one without the other as these go hand in hand.

Very well put I heartily agree with your answer

Thanks GRM for the up vote and good words.
